# Concluding vs Concludingly

Tags: adverbs, sentence-starts

My English teacher has taught me to use "Concluding" when writing the end part of certain texts (next to other words).
Example:

> Concluding, we can say that...

To me it somehow sounds curious. "Concluding**ly**" sounds way better. And we say "Unfortunate**ly**" and not "Unfortunate", right (although this similarity might be related to the "-ing" suffix of "Concluding")?

Could someone shed some light on this controversy?

Comment: "Concludingly" means exactly nothing here. It's a nonsensical word. "Concluding" as a stand-alone doesn't work either: you'd have to dress it up to use it properly: "Before concluding this ..." or something. The sensible way to begin that kind of sentence is to begin it with "In conclusion ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Concludingly* has some slight use.  To give you some idea of how slight, the google finds 300M hits for "in conclusion" and 13K hits for "concludingly."   Here are the results for your locution:

"Concludingly, we can say" 118
"Concluding, we can say" 18.5K
"In conclusion, we can say" 139K

The Ngram viewer shows the same skew for books.

The use of *concluding* here is that of the nominative absolute, a participial phrase (here of just one word, the participle) that applies to the subject+verb combination of the main clause.

(We say *unfortunately* because we need the adverbial form. *Unfortunate* is an adjective.)

Answer (score 1):

*Concludingly* is obsolete, and doesn't mean what you would expect it to mean. From the OED:

*conˈcludingly, adv.*

*Obs.*

*Conclusively, decisively.*

Using *concluding* is a bit odd, and I have never heard it used in the way you illustrate. It is not really a participle phrase as participle phrases are adjectival and need a noun or pronoun to modify, and the phrase itself requires an object for the action in the participle: -

"Concluding(*participle*) his speech(*direct object*), Arthur(*noun*) ran from the stage"

I would recommend using "In conclusion" rather than "Concluding".

Comment: "Concluding" sounds really odd to me too. Thing is, my teacher doesn't receive criticism very well, so confronting her with this will just result in "the Internet's crap." and all.